# Dickey fuller test for stationarity check

Tags: time-series, stationary-processes

I have been implementing dickey fuller test after gaining an understanding of its procedure.. The relevant equations are

[image]

[image]

I have obtained the value for t-stat as +ve and hence when comparing with the table for alpha= 0.05 the result shows it is not stationary. I am confident that my data is stationary because on plotting the data it's stationary.

What I dont understand is how can the t-stat value ever be negative when numtr and denmtr are positive. The theta value or p_hat is positive(by OLS estimation) and SE as it has squares in the equation will also yield a +ve value.

**My assumption:**

Can it be because, rooting in SE gives -ve value(as square of a number, both +ve and -ve is the same). Or my theta value has to be -ve but can that be?

Any help on this great thanx.

**Edit made:** Image After seasonality removed for m = 4
[image]

**Edit done(2)** Before seasonality

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Dickey Fuller test tests between two cases: unit root (integrated time series), which is the null hypothesis and a stationary time series which is the alternative hypothesis.  In writing the model for the test (by differencing the AR model), the coefficient for the $y_{t-1}$ term is $p=\rho-1$. 
$$\Delta y_t=p y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$$

$p$ being positive means $\rho > 1$ which is explosive growth, which you said from a plot of the series is obviously not the case.  So the test is being used to only distinguish between $p<0$ and the null, $p=0$.

It's not true that the numerator in the test statistic is positive. It's negative and the denominator is always positive.

As to why you got it positive in your OLS, 
Did you apply differencing? Enough number of times?

Btw, are you using the right one of the three versions of the test?
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickey–Fuller_test

Comment: Thanks lots for the replyy...What I tried is OLS estimation for p_hat using the formula $\sum_i(y*x) / \sum_i (x^2) $ obtained for the eqn $ y = \theta * x$. For the airline dataset, I have taken log transformation and then first order differencing..PLs point out where I went wrong..

Comment: Is the $\theta$ (p_hat) value different for the equation $\Delta{y_t} = p*y_{t-1} +\epsilon_t$ using OLS?

Comment: Yes.  You should try first with that equation. If the coefficient is positive, take the series $z_t=y_t- y_{t-1}$. And  if that still is giving you a positive coefficient, try it on the series $w_t=z_t- z_{t-1}$ and so on.   If am in a remote area with no computer, just phone, so cannot see you data set etc.  So, please include as much detail in your equations if further discussion needed. If wishing to show a figure, you could edit your question to include the figure.

Comment: PLease can u go through https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2497722/what-is-the-ols-estimate-for-deltay-t-py-t-1-epsilon-t?noredirect=1#comment5159453_2497722

Comment: Also see the edit made

Comment: The column E graph shows seasonality.  You should remove seasonality first.

Comment: Thanx for the replyy..Can you guide as of how to detect seasonality from dataset or plot and which strategy to remove them.

Comment: My knowledge was to apply log transformation and then differencing to make a non-stationary data into stationary one. I have seen many sites specifying the same.

Comment: Well, because every fourth point in the plot dips down (seems like quarterly data). You can read about seasonality and seasonal adjustment on wiki here (look for the regression analysis section) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seasonality

Comment: For your specific situation, though, this website would offer you the most direct way to deal with it. https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/1

Comment: Thank u much for the worthy guidance!.. one question is how many values will be there be after seasonal differencing of data. For m = 4(since quarterly data) is it T - 4 ??

Comment: Also please see the added image above. I feel yet it is not stationary. Am I correct

Comment: This looks like it could be stationary.  What did the DF test show? Negative coefficient? Yes, of course, differencing would cause 3 fewer points.

Comment: yes..I could get -ve coefficient as -0.0002 but value is not less than -1.95 (5% significance level). Just to note : since T-4 values will be present while plotting graph I have given 0 value to first four records!

Comment: Try differencing the series one more time. What is the new DF coefficient then?

Comment: Sorry.. a mistake...I have obtained −0.000285953 as DF test value after performing seasonal diff and then first order diff...After seasonal diff alone the value was positive

Comment: I mean one more diff after that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68185/discussion-between-devi-and-mathemagical).

Comment: Did it work now?

Comment: The latest result obtained is  -1.5702.

Comment: How can one understand the number of times of differencing ? or do I have to modify seasonal differencing with another m value to cut the steps of first differencing.

Comment: Nothing wrong or hacky about differencing too many times. If you have to do differencing m times to reach stationarity, the series is called "integrated of order m".  You can google search that term or just "stationarity" to read more.  I think I need to try for a

Comment: Seasonality - I think what you have already done is enough. The data was visibly quarterly so other periods are not useful to try.

Comment: Curious to know how many times you had to difference to get stationarity

Comment: I have tried 15 times and yet not smaller than -1.95. Is there any sense in differencing this way ?

Comment: ACF plot of transformed data.. can it help some way to foresee the steps/no.of steps to be undertaken for stationarity

Comment: Yeah.  15 is way more than normal. 2 or 3 and after that the pursuit is usually fruitless. ACF (which is not shown) can suggest what lag to use for seasonality, but I don’t see how it can be used for finding the order of integration. You have removed the 3 plots you first had, but if I recall right there was a trend as well? Did you try the models with drift and trend for the DF test?

Comment: See the edit made

Comment: I mean the original data looked like it had drift too, right?

Comment: What is the difference between seasonality and drift ?

Comment: Moreover, will the theta estimate change when considering the regression equation with drift term added ?